# How to convert a TeX file with lualatex-script?

Tags: luatex, conversion

I want to convert a TeX file to a PDF file with a lua script. I can execute the `lualatex.exe` with

```
os.execute("...path\lualatex.exe")
```

Then I have to fill it out by hand, which file should be convert. But how can I convert a specific file, for example `test.tex`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If the `myfile.tex` file can be assumed to be in a directory that's searched by the TeX distribution, `os.execute(lualatex myfile)` should do the job.

Comment: You're welcome! I'll post my answer as an official answer so that this question can be considered to have been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file `test.tex` can be assumed to be in a directory that's searched by the TeX distribution, then

```
os.execute(lualatex test)
```

should do the job.